# Oval for PCA axis

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Does anyone know what concept the below is referring to?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the Bivariate Normal distribution. $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix and $\Delta$ is the Mahalanobis distance, representing the distance of the test point $x$ from the mean $\mu$. The points of constant value of $\Delta ^2$ form an ellipse whose principal axes are defined by the eigenvectors $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ of $\Sigma$.

Comment: thank you for that!